# How to set up a Twitter follow button that will enable another button after following

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I'm trying to set up a follow system for my site and it seem to be not working.
I'm trying to add a Twitter follow button that will enable another button after clicking it.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function enableButton2() {
            document.getElementById("button2").disabled = false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://twitter.com/appsboss7" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @appsboss7</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs'); onclick="enableButton2()" </script>
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="button 2" disabled />
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it?
Thanks ahead,
Appsboss7

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that youre trying to put this: `onclick="enableButton2()` inside the script tag.

The onclick event should be attached to the rendered button that comes from twitters API.

However, since that button gets renderd on page load, you must attach it somehow after the page has loaded.

The easiest solution is to use jquery for this.

Example:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '#your-twitter-button-id-here' ).click(function() {
        enableButton2();
    });
});
<script>
```

Comment: Hi henrik, the solution caused the Twitter button to disable the itself after following the person mentioned there. Do you know how to make it enable to 2nd button as well? Cause the code seem to be not working.
Here are 2 screenshots displays what happens:
http://prntscr.com/92l2av
http://prntscr.com/92l2ep

Hope that you can help me fix this,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<body>
<a href="https://twitter.com/appsboss7" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @appsboss7</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs'); onclick="enableButton2()" </script>
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="button 2"  />
</body>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/h790n5u5/1/)

Comment: Hi, the code doesn't work.
It just enables the 2nd button before clicking and following the Twitter account.
Thanks for the attempt to help though!